# ¿Por qué no puedo determinar la clase de un elemento en CSS?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un pequeño juego en el que los usuarios deben adivinar qué nota musical está sonando. Se me ocurrió que sería un buen añadido el utilizar un piano para marcar la nota, y buscando, me encontré con [este piano, de Philip Zastrow](https://codepen.io/zastrow/pen/kxdYdk) hecho en CSS.

Philip lo ha hecho utilizando solo un `<ul>` y varios `<li>` (cada tecla es un elemento de la lista). El problema es que yo también tengo otras listas, así que no puedo utilizar directamente su CSS en mi web. Como el `<ul>` tiene la clase `set` y es el elemento *root*, decidí modificar todas las declaraciones CSS añadiendo la referencia al `ul.set`, pues así solo debería aplicarse ese estilo a las listas del piano. Esperaba que todo funcionara bien, pero me di cuenta de que una (solo una declaración) se rompe. Es la referente a la lista (`<li>`).

Me he dado cuenta de que, si modifico la declaración `li` a `ul li`, funciona (la lista está en un `ul`), pero no ocurre lo mismo si uso `ul.set li` (sería lo necesario, pues quiero que solo aplique al `ul` con la clase `set`).

Por ejemplo, esto funciona:

```
li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

Y esto también funciona:

```
ul li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

Pero esto ya no:

```
ul.set li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}
```

Realmente no le veo sentido, y llevo un buen rato dándole vueltas sin ver qué hago mal, porque el `ul` tiene la clase `set`.

Incorporo el código aquí abajo, ojalá podáis ayudarme.

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box
}

body {
  margin:0;
  background:#222
}

ul.set {
  height:18.875em;
  width:34em;
  margin:5em auto;
  padding:3em 0 0 3em;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #160801;
  border-radius:1em;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0)),url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/187/vwood.png);
  box-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset,0 1px rgba(212,152,125,0.2) inset,0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
/* AQUÍ ESTÁ EL ERROR */
/* 'li' funciona, pero 'ul.set li' rompe el estilo, idk why */
ul li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

ul.set .white {
  height:16em;
  width:4em;
  z-index:1;
  border-left:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  box-shadow:-1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset,0 0 5px #ccc inset,0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#eee 0%,#fff 100%)
}

ul.set .white:active {
  border-top:1px solid #777;
  border-left:1px solid #999;
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
  box-shadow:2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset,-5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset,0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%)
}

.black {
  height:8em;
  width:2em;
  margin:0 0 0 -1em;
  z-index:2;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset,0 -5px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset,0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,#222 0%,#555 100%)
}

.black:active {
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset,0 -2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset,0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#444 0%,#222 100%)
}

.a,.g,.f,.d,.c {
  margin:0 0 0 -1em
}

ul.set li:first-child {
  border-radius:5px 0 5px 5px
}

ul.set li:last-child {
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px
}
```

```html
<ul class="set">
  <li class="white b"></li>
  <li class="black as"></li>
  <li class="white a"></li>
  <li class="black gs"></li>
  <li class="white g"></li>
  <li class="black fs"></li>
  <li class="white f"></li>
  <li class="white e"></li>
  <li class="black ds"></li>
  <li class="white d"></li>
  <li class="black cs"></li>
  <li class="white c"></li>
</ul>
```

También os adjunto mi [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tupiet/pen/xxWLWZE), por si necesitáis hacer algún cambio.

Muchísimas gracias, y eso, ojalá podáis ayudarme, porque no entiendo qué falla.

Comment: Prueba declarandola asi : ul.set > li {  //Aca tu css }

Comment: @David081 Gracias por el consejo y el tiempo, lo acabo de probar, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Creo que es redundante acceder **ul.set**, si deseas acceder al elemento solo indica la clase **.set > li{ //estilos}**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @AntonioGalicia, realmente es redundante, pero lo hice para ver si de esta forma funcionaba. `.set > li` tampoco funciona. No entiendo por qué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba así:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box
}

body {
  margin:0;
  background:#222
}

.set {
  height:18.875em;
  width:34em;
  margin:5em auto;
  padding:3em 0 0 3em;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #160801;
  border-radius:1em;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0)),url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/187/vwood.png);
  box-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(0,0,0,0.5) inset,0 1px rgba(212,152,125,0.2) inset,0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}

.white, .black{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
}

.set .white {
  height:16em;
  width:4em;
  z-index:1;
  border-left:1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom:1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  box-shadow:-1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8) inset,0 0 5px #ccc inset,0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#eee 0%,#fff 100%)
}

.set .white:active {
  border-top:1px solid #777;
  border-left:1px solid #999;
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
  box-shadow:2px 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset,-5px 5px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset,0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0%,#e9e9e9 100%)
}

.black {
  height:8em;
  width:2em;
  margin:0 0 0 -1em;
  z-index:2;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset,0 -5px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset,0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,#222 0%,#555 100%)
}

.black:active {
  box-shadow:-1px -1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.2) inset,0 -2px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6) inset,0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background:linear-gradient(to right,#444 0%,#222 100%)
}

.a,.g,.f,.d,.c {
  margin:0 0 0 -1em
}

.set li:first-child {
  border-radius:5px 0 5px 5px
}

.set li:last-child {
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 5px
}

.TEST {
  color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="set">
  <li class="white b"></li>
  <li class="black as"></li>
  <li class="white a"></li>
  <li class="black gs"></li>
  <li class="white g"></li>
  <li class="black fs"></li>
  <li class="white f"></li>
  <li class="white e"></li>
  <li class="black ds"></li>
  <li class="white d"></li>
  <li class="black cs"></li>
  <li class="white c"></li>
</ul>

<!--UNA LISTA CUALQUIERA -->
<ul class="TEST">
  <li class="AAA">UNO</li>
  <li class="AAA">DOS</li>
  <li class="AAA">TRES</li>
</ul>
```

Solo llama a sus clases por ejemplo `.white, .black{}`

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Esto funciona. ¿Puedo preguntar por qué funciona solo declarando las clases, y no si especifico también el elemento?